# Yii2. Many inputs for one Model/DB field

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

How such inputs could be translated into DATE field in DB?

[image]

Customer insisted on such way to input user birthdate. First my thought was simply to concat in one field in `beforeValidate`, but after this inputs won't be able to display date, that was inputed, from the DB. How to avoid such restriction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add these 3 fields as virtual properties in the model class.
2. In `beforeValidate()` set the value of `birthdate` with combination of 3 virtual fields from the form.
3. Add `afterFind()` in the model class where value of saved in DB `birthdate` property is used to set the values of 3 virtual properties.
4. Now form properly holds 3 fields' values and combined date is saved in DB.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. By "virtual fields" you mean adding fields to the "rules" array, but not creating a real field in the model class? In my case `[['birthdate_month', 'birthdate_day', 'birthdate_year'], 'string']`

Comment: To the rules and to the model itself like `public $birthdate_month;`